# Rotation to obtain x coordinate

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given: $x0$ , $y0$, $x2$ and $y1$  points and angle $A$.

How to compute $x1$ in the figure specified.

Note :
 ($x0$ , $y0$) maybe to the left of ($x2$ , $y1$) as well.

Sorry if the question seems trivial. I have forgot much of geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1090184
Point labels: $P_0(x_0\mid y_0),P_1(x_1\mid y_1),P_2(x_2\mid y_1)$
I'll use $\alpha$ instead of $A$ for the angle of rotation , if you please. And $\beta$ for the angle that ${P_0}{P_2}$ makes with the $x$-axis.

1. $\tan{\beta}={{y_1-y_0}\over{x_2-x_0}}$.
2. $\tan(\alpha+\beta)={{\tan{\alpha}+\tan{\beta}}\over{1-{\tan{\alpha}}·{\tan{\beta}}}}$.
3. $x_1={{{y_1-y_0}\over{\tan(\alpha+\beta)}}+x_0}$

Comment: Just to confirm is this applicable when $\beta$ is acute as well as obtuse.

Comment: @Abhishek Bhatia \\ In the case wherein ${\tan(\alpha+\beta)}=0$ (meaning that the rotated line is parallel to the $x$-axis), all bets are off, of course.

Comment: Great. Should have figured it out. Anyways for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b = \sqrt{|x0-x2|^2 + |y0-y1|^2}$, let $c = \sqrt{|x0-x1|^2 + |y0-y1|^2}$, and let $a=|x2-x1|$ ,so these are the sidelengths of the triangle.

We should be able to use the law of cosines now and isolate $x1$: 
$$
    a^2 = b^2 + c^2 -2bc\cos(A) \\ \dotsc
$$

This looks like it might be kinda messy.